# The type name does not exist while opening an old project in Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2, crystal-reports

One of my C# project contains many crystal reports. All reports done on my machine and worked perfectly. But after a fresh installation of windows I've installed visual studio 2010, Crystal Report 13.0.13 and sql server 2008 r2. But I cannot run my project in visual studio. It shows below errors.

> **Error   1 :**   The type name 'ReportSource' does not exist in the type
>   'WindowsFormsApplication1.CrystalDecisions'
>
> **Error   2 :**   The type name 'CrystalReports' does not exist in the type
>   'WindowsFormsApplication1.CrystalDecisions'   D:\Completing\WindowsFormsApplication1\led.cs
>
> **Error   3 :**   The type name 'Shared' does not exist
>
> **Error   4 :**   The type or namespace name 'ReportClass' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   D:\Completing\WindowsFormsApplication1\led.cs

These are the errors. But I've added these namespace to project reference. But it's not working giving the same error. The project target framework is '.NET Framework 4'. I cannot get rid from these error. Can anyone please help me to go out from these.

Comment: you should include the references of dlls to include in Project Properties> prequities> set all dll to include

Comment: @manraj can u please explain me in detail how to do this...

Comment: i've added all references to the project but cannot build the project it shows above errors the problems continues with crystal report i don't no how to come out with this error

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling the setup the connection to reports might have changed try giving proper connection to report connection string